# error on Implement interface in main class

Tags: java

Hi friends im learning java from basics..

I have some doubt in implementing interface.

**WORKING CODE**

Using interface in a class is working....

```
interface bala
   {

    void prnt();
   }

class ex implements bala{
    @Override
    public void prnt() {
        System.out.print("hi");
    }
}

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    ex p = new ex();
    p.prnt();
    }
 }
```

**NOT WORKING**

Here is my doubt, why i cant implement interface in main method?
plea

```
interface bala
  {
     void prnt();
  }

  public class Solution implements bala
    {
        public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        prnt();
    }

@Override
public void prnt() {
    System.out.println("hi");

  }
 }
```

What is happening here?
Why implementing on main() is not working?
Is there is a way to make working interface on main function?

Comment: It's not working because you cannot call non-static methods in a static context.

Comment: Copy the error you get from the compiler, paste it in google search, and read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working, because you're trying to access non-static (i.e. instance) method from a static context.

In order to invoke it, you need an instance of the `Solution` class (note that in your working code you have an instance of the `ex` class, so here you need to do the same with slight difference):

```
Solution instance = new Solution();
instance.prnt();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Given Bellow code works well.    
   interface bala
  {
 void prnt();
```

}

```
 public class Solution implements bala
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
{
    Solution sol = new Solution();
   sol.prnt();
}


public void prnt() {
System.out.println("hi");

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is main() is static, static blocks can access static members or with object reference . So here you could simply create an object/instance to invoke the method:

```
new Solution().prnt();
```

Answer (score 2):

try `new Solution().prnt()` instead of calling `prnt()`

the problem is :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

main method is a static method. And your overridden method is non-static. You can't call non-static methods from static context.

In order to call overridden method prnt() to call, you need to instantiate you Solution class like -

```
Solution sol = new Solution();
```

and then

```
sol.prnt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Best Option to Do it . Create the instance of `class` and Access it.since main `method` is a static method you can do like that

```
Solution instance = new Solution();//Creating instance of class
instance.prnt();//access prnt .
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the object of Solution class in main method

```
Solution s1 = new Solution();
s1.print();
```

Otherwise, you can create the method as static because you are trying to access 
the method from static context.